# Breakpoints not working in Eclipse with XDebug

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have been trying to set up debugging using XDebug in Eclipse for the last few hours without success.

I have the following in my etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
```

The zend_extensions = /usr/lib...... was given to me by the custom installation instructions on the XDebug site. I followed the setup instructions exactly as they are on that page - http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

But from what I have read typing the command php -m should show XDebug twice, once under PHP modules and once under Zend modules. Well it is showing up under neither for me. So it seems that XDebug is not getting loaded at all?

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this problem and get XDebug working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've editted `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file which is for **apache**. You'd want to edit `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` for the command line interface's options.

If you pass in the phpinfo() from a web site, that PHP has run through Apache of course. And then the wizard will give you settings for the Apache set-up. If you would have passed the phpinfo() output (`php -i`) from the command line, it would have given you the settings for the CLI.

Comment: OK, i put that into /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and now the breakpoints are working when I select Debug as PHP Script, but they don't work for Debug as PHP Web Page. Any ideas?

Comment: Jim, you'll have to make path mappings. In order to see whether it works from the Xdebug site, make a remote debug log (xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/remote.txt) and see what's happening there.

Comment: Nevermind, had to change some settings in Debug Configurations

Comment: I also would like to know, please.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me, the first time I setup xdebug in Eclipse it worked just fine, but the next time I tried it, it wasn't stopping at breakpoints. After a lot of research it turned out that I had 2 Eclipse instances running (one for Java and another for Php) and that caused some kind of issues with the debugger.

After closing both instances and starting Eclipse with php workspace first and then Eclipse with java workspace, xdebug worked fine again. My only idea is that debug port was already used when I tried to use it; or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

An other common problem is that you use a router to get through INTERNET and that you had to forward XDEBUG PORT (generaly 9000) on your PC to make XDEBUG working with ECLIPSE.
But your router gives a dynamic IP to your PC and one day your mobile phone connects to the router before your PC and gets the IP address you configuredon you router IP FORWARDING !
The solution getting a static IP from your router. Here is an explanation: [http://webologix.com/fr/blog/xdebug-eclipse-fonctionnement-aleatoire.html](https://webologix.com/fr/blog/xdebug-eclipse-fonctionnement-aleatoire.html)